# Java HTMLUnit WebClient perceives enabled JavaScript as disabled, when parsin' t' page

Tags: java, http, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

As stated.

Used 2 B getting some JS error messages, but able to parse t' page partly now.

Still, among some largely generic am seeing the next message:

```js
    <noscript>
      &lt;strong&gt;We're sorry but client doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.&lt;/strong&gt;
    </noscript>
```

My code:

```
public void getContent(String startUrl) {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new SilentJavaScriptErrorListener());

    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30 * 1000);
    // webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    // webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);

    try {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(startUrl);

        // webClient.getCurrentWindow().getJobManager().removeAllJobs();
        webClient.close();

        System.out.println(page.getPage().getTitleText());

        System.out.println(page.getBody().getVisibleText());

        List<?> sportsItems = page.getByXPath("//a");

        System.out.println(sportsItems.size());

        System.out.println(page.asXml());

        sportsItems.forEach(System.out::println);

        webClient.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any useful tips or alternatives here.
Thanks in advance!

Update:

Actually, I think I may have understood the reason for such an output: SilentJavaScriptErrorListener usage.

But I added it for a reason: in order to eliminate the errors arising without it from interfering with the output.

Maybe, there's some other way for that, but I haven't found it yet) So, a little update + still eager for other thoughts as well.

Thanks.

Comment: The noscript tag is not necessarily an error, but HTMLUnit's Javascript engine may not support all the features the site needs.  Some site's will also check visibility api, which can be a problem with headless browsers.

Comment: @pcalkins Actually, I think I may have understood the reason for such an output: SilentJavaScriptErrorListener usage. But I added it for a reason: in order to eliminate the errors arising without it from interfering with the output. Maybe, there's some other way for that, but I haven't found it yet) So, a little update + still eager for other thoughts as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is not the SilentJavaScriptErrorListener; this one only supresses some log output.

The case is different - the page your are requesting does some js checks (by running some js inside the page/your browser) to figure out if js is enabled at all and if the required js functions are supported by your browser.

HtmlUnit is good at supporting js but some newer js features are not supported at the moment. (Usually the log output you see without the SilentJavaScriptErrorListener point to this).

What to do?

If you can provide the url (maybe by private mail) i can have a look and check if it is possible to add/fix the missing piece in the js support of HtmlUnit.

If not there is also the option to have install some workaround by patching the server response and remove the js check - but maybe this makes the rest of the page not working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

Yes, I surely can provide you the url, as it's a public site anyway.

 And, for a sample, "https://google.com" is proceeded okay overall, both with SilentJavaScriptErrorListener on and off, so..

Comment: Please share the url - i will have a look.

Comment: https://leon.bet/ru/bets